# Airflow how to write API request results to BigQuery table or GCS file

Tags: google-bigquery, cloud, airflow, pipeline

I am a novice trying to use Airflow to create a simple pipeline which gets data from an API and stores it in a BigQuery table. I have been successful decoding the json returned by the API and printing it out. I am stuck trying to figure out how to store that data into  a file in GCS or somewhere so that then use I can use GCStoBigqueryOperator to load the data into BigQuery. I haven't found any operator that allows me to create a file, populate it and store it in a bucket.

Also is this the right approach for this pipeline?

Thank you

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import Request
import json

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "email": "admin@localhost.com",
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
}

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'api-auth-accountid': '00000-0rererekl09rtlkjescgy0-0-ete90-et',
        'api-auth-applicationkey': 'rre9gr45jk34594gft-3it30it'
    }

  


def download_sales():
    
    request1 = Request(
        'https://inventory.dvvvvvvtems.com/ExternalApi/v2/saleList?Limit=50&CreatedSince=2021-1-1', headers=headers)

    sale_list = urlopen(request1).read()
    dec_sale_list = json.loads(sale_list)
    for sale in dec_sale_list['SaleList']:
        print("sale ID: " + sale['SaleID'] + " Customer:" + sale['Customer'] + " Order Date: " + sale['OrderDate'])

        s_id = sale['SaleID']
        request2 = Request(f'https://inventory.dfakesysjhghtems.com/ExternalApi/t3/sale/order?SaleID={s_id}', headers=headers)
        order_list = urlopen(request2).read()
        dec_item_list = json.loads(order_list)
        for sku in dec_item_list['Lines']:
            print("SKU: " + sku['SKU'] + " Product: " + sku['Name'] + " Quantity: " + str(sku['Quantity']) + " Price:  " + str(sku['Price'])+ " Total:  " + str(sku['Total']))

with DAG("sales_data_pipeline", start_date=datetime(2021, 1 ,1),
    schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:


    downloading_sales = PythonOperator(
        task_id="downloading_sales",
        python_callable=download_sales
```